# Blank Screen upon login after installing openGL

Tags: unity, 13.10, xorg, display, opengl

I have an Inspiron N5010 running Ubuntu13.10 64b. It uses Intal HD Graphics (i.e. no ATI/Nvidia graphics card)

I need a software that uses OpenGL, and I installed multiple packages using synaptic that had the word "opengl"

Now, system boots up fne, but I only get a blank screen when I login (I can see and move the mouse pointer). Closing the laptop lid, or pressing Ctrl+Alt+L gives me the usual lock screen w/o any problems.

After opening tty1, I ran startx which again switched to a black screen. Going back to tty1, I saw startx was stuck at Loading Extension GLX.
Used Ctrl+C to close it

After googling, I tried

```
sudo apt-get reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get unity
```

but it did not help

Any ideas on what I should do now?

Comment: Did you get the problem solved?  I am stuck at exact same point.

Comment: I tried uninstalling recently installed packages by reading the list from **/var/log/apt/history.log** .
Unfortunately there were too many recent ones there, and I had an assignment, so I reinstalled Ubuntu